# How to process string in using awk in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ksh

I am very new to shell scripting and have to do so many tasks around it. I am trying to learn as fast a possible but some times shell scripting makes a task look very easy and at other times it just toys with me. And I am facing similar situation now.
I have a command  which gives me an output like this.

```
 File                  Dependents
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
<File> is a requisite of <Dependents>
Path: /usr/lib/obj
  Java 1.0.0.0          analysis 0.0.0.2
                        runtime 1.2.0.0
                        client 1.2.0.0
                        framework 6.1.9.100
                        sguide 1.9.10.0
                        sysmgt 6.1.9.100
                        dsm 6.1.9.200

Path: /etc/obj
  Java 1.0.0.0          analysis 1.2.0.2
                        runtime 2.0.0.0
                        client3 6.1.9.0
                        sysmgt 6.1.9.0
                        dsm2 6.1.9.0
```

Now I want to get the list of dependencies into an array for further processing. This is what I am able to do so far:

```
<command> | cut -f1 | grep '[a-z]' | grep -v File | grep -v : | awk '{ print $1}'
```

output is:

```
Java<<< I want this to be analysis
runtime
client
framework
sguide
sysmgt
dsm

Java<<< want this to be analysis
runtime
client3
sysmgt
dsm2
```

I have to capture these two lists in two separate arrays.

Can someone please help me in achieving this output in an elegant way. I don't want to butcher this code with my brute force method involving lot of conditions and comparisions.

Comment: You'll do better reading up on awk arrays and keeping your processing all in the final `awk` script (in your pipeline). Without knowing what your final processing is going to look like it is hard to comment/help further. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ arr1=$(command ... | awk -v c=1 '!NF{f=0} f && s==c{print $1} /Java/{f=1; s++; if(s==c) print $(NF-1)}')

$ arr2=$(command ... | awk -v c=2 '!NF{f=0} f && s==c{print $1} /Java/{f=1; s++; if(s==c) print $(NF-1)}')

$ echo $arr1
analysis runtime client framework sguide sysmgt dsm

$ echo $arr2
analysis runtime client3 sysmgt dsm2
```

perhaps better if you run the command once and split the results into two arrays.

**Explanation**

> `awk -v c=1`  set awk variable c to 1 (describes group instance number)
>
> `'!NF{f=0}` if there are no fields (empty line) reset f
>
> `f && s==c{print $1}`  if f is set and counter equals to c print the first field
>
> `/Java/{f=1; s++;`  when pattern matched to Java, set f and increment counter and
> `...if(s==c) print $(NF-1)}'` if counter matches c print the penultimate field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain 
'!NF{f=0} f && s==c{print $1} /Java/{f=1; s++; if(s==c) print $(NF-1)}'
This is a master stroke but I am so far unable to decode it.

Comment: All I have understood is that print $(NF-1)} is used to get the last-1 field and the rest of the instructions are for getting a start and end condition. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your solution by removing the substring with Java first:

```
command | sed 's/Java [^ ]*//' | cut -f1 | grep '[a-z]' | grep -v File | grep -v : | awk '{ print $1}'
```

When you use `awk`, you can better use the full strength of `awk`. Just say you want the print the second last field of any line with a number:

```
command | awk '/[0-9]/ { print $(NF-1) }'
```

This is better than trying to use `sed` (do you have tabs or spaces?)

```
command | sed -n '/[0-9].[0-9]/ s/^.* \([^ ]*\) .*/\1/p'
```

A funny solution is using `rev` to revert your text. That way `cut` can find the second field.

```
command | grep '[0-9].[0-9]' | rev | cut -d " " -f2 | rev
```

For people who only read the last line, I will repeat the `awk` solution:

```
command | awk '/[0-9]/ { print $(NF-1) }'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing many wonderful ways. But the above one suits my need better so I am accepting that